# HTML 5 Video for mobile

Tags: html, video, mobile, converters

I had done the HTML5 native video playing with Android (Samsung Galaxy pop gts5570) mobile steps I have done and its get work perfectly with Opera Mobile 11.10

1. Upload the video through YouTube
2. downloaded through keepvid.com in 3gp format
3. done through the following code

   ```
   <video width="320" id="video" height="240" onclick="this.play()" autoplay="autoplay" controls="controls" style="border:4px solid #00C;background:#636465;">
       <source src="video/1.3gp"/>
   </video>
   ```

but I have encoded the files using some converter to 3gp format but that not working,which convert will convert it correctly? thanks in advance.

Comment: @John Green-> Your correct i did encoding myself thats not working so that i am asking which can converter as same 3gp format.

Comment: As no one helped I have found the solution by my self I think this may help to some one .... handbreak is the convert which has the facility to make the video playable in mobile web browser 1) choose the iphone & ipod in preset setting 2) Enable the web optimized then convert it ... it will work in mobile web

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have found the solution by my self, I feel this may help to some one .... **handbreak** is the convert which has the facility to make the video playable in mobile web browser

1) choose the iphone & ipod in preset setting

2) Enable the web optimized then convert it ... it will work in mobile web

**UPDATE**

another HTML5 converter is available now in [easy html5 video](http://easyhtml5video.com/)